# Legality in Standard of Standard-legal cards from previous printings

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-standard

Say I have a copy of Llanowar Elves from the 2017 Core Set. Can I put it in a current Standard deck, or do I need to have a version from currently Standard-legal set?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Answered [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15363/can-you-play-older-versions-of-cards-in-standard&ved=2ahUKEwi5xZP3773fAhUUSY8KHfLFDssQjjgwAHoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0axLimJ9y9ksbyGLZD08wm).

> Yes. The only thing that matters for determining card legality is the name of the card. As far as the Oracle is concerned, 2 different printings of shockare the exact same card for all game and tournament rule purposes